# How to withdraw rewards with aave's LendingPool?

Tags: solidity, aave

Let's say a contract deposits money into Aave with `LendingPool.deposit()`. After a while, we use `LendingPool.withdraw()`. Will it withdraw all rewards and interest? It doesn't seem so?

https://docs.aave.com/developers/the-core-protocol/lendingpool

Comment: It says so explicitly in in the docs. What reason do you have to believe otherwise?

Comment: @SamuelDare So `LendingPool.withdraw()` will send all deposited amount + interest + other rewards (like Matic)?

Answer (score 1):

When you deposit into Aave, you receive `aTokens` in return. The balance of that token keeps on increasing in your wallet as more interest gets accumulated.

Calling the `withdraw()` function with the required amount would unwrap `aToken` back to `underlyingToken`. This accounts for initial deposit + interest if you unwrap your entire `aToken` balance.

To claim additional rewards like Matic, call `claimRewards()` on the `IncentivesController` controller.
Address for the same is given here: https://docs.aave.com/developers/deployed-contracts/matic-polygon-market